# sql combining output of 2 columns into one column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've following tables

```
person: id,name
1, mani
2, senthil
3, jack
4, alan

relation: relname,id1,id2 (id1 and id2 refers to person.id)
rel1, 1,3
rel2, 2,3
rel1, 4,1
```

I want to form a query that returns the ids of person that are related one after another. Query should return:

```
1
3
2
3
4
1
```

Here `(1,3)` is pair, followed by `(2,3)` and so on.

Can you please form such a query?

Comment: Any particular flavour of database?

Comment: @stefa the repay is knowledge.

Comment: Is `relname` supposed to be the PK here? It has a duplicate value in your example data...

Comment: All the 3 fields in relation form composite key

Comment: Actually the query will based on relname I.e. Getting all relations with given name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One Way (assumes `id1,id2` is a composite PK to avoid duplicates)

```
SELECT id
FROM
(
select id1 as id, id1,id2 from relation
union all
select id2 as id, id1,id2 from relation
) T
ORDER BY id1,id2
```

If your RDBMS supports `UNPIVOT` you may be able to do this with one scan through the table.

Comment: Thanks. I am not near a machine to check it out. Will check and get back later.

Comment: Brilliant! This works! I had been breaking my head for hours on this. How did you go about thinking to solve this? Unfortunately, SQLite doesn't support UNPIVOT.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id1 from relation
union
select id2 from relation
```

(but the order won't be the one in your example).

You could also iterate through the pairs and build a list :

```
// metalanguage
resultSet = executeQuery("select id1, id2 from relation");
List list = new List();
while (resultSet.hasNext()) {
    list.add(resultSet.get("id1");
    list.add(resultSet.get("id2");
}
```

Comment: Misses the "one after another" for a pair requirement

Comment: The downvote wasn't mine but suspect the OP is looking for a query to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could first try to create column result like CSV

```
 1,3,2,3,4,1
```

And afterwards from this CVS retrieve rows.

The creation of this query depend of DBMS you use.

I think that using some internet search engine (amazon,bing, google) we will be able to solve this by your own.

Comment: CSV will not help here as this result is input to another query.